# Create an android app that controls other apps

Tags: java, android, mobile

Could I create an Android app with the ability to control another android applications? For example to press and click on things in another android app while my hypothetical application would be running?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used or questions about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Comment: Your question is vague and isn't likely to get any answers, but you might want to look at accessibility services. These services are intended to be used by people with disabilities (blind, etc.), but you may find something here that can help you:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService

Comment: Accessibility services are your best bet, but unless you're actually an accessibility aid you won't be allowed on the Play Store.  If this is a personal app, you're probably ok.